# Refactor class method to rails 4 scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, named-scope

I have the following method that I'd like to move to named scope

```
def self.running_promotion
  Supplier.all.select { |s| s.has_running_promotion? == true }
end
```

Not sure how to use `lambda` with rails 4 scope or if this is possible. I tried

```
scope :on_sale, -> { where({ |s| s.has_running_promotion? == true }) }
```

Answer (score 1):

if `has_running_promotion` is field in your table you could write:

```
scope :on_sale, -> { where(has_running_promotion: true) }
```

Comment: yes, but it doesn't. `has_running_promotion?` is a method

Comment: if you don't have `has_running_promtion` field, add your `has_running_promtion?` is not related to it, so maybe your should add your `has_running_promotion?` method to question